# Finding the distribution of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have this question-

> Let $X \sim Uniform(0,1)$ .
>    $f_Y(y)= 1-|1-y|$ when $0 < y < 2$ and $0$ otherwise.
>   It is also given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then find the distribution of $(X+Y)$.

I have been trying to solve this using transformation technique,i.e $(X,Y) \to (U=X+Y,V=Y)$ and after finding the joint pdf of $(U,V)$ I have to integrate out $v$ to get the pdf of $(X+Y)$. But I am having a hard time finding the region of integration because I cannot separate the cases.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: There's a problem with density of $Y$. It integrates to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @DominikKutek edited that typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
f_X(x)
=
\begin{cases}
1 & x\in[0,1],
\\
0 & \text{else,}
\end{cases}
\qquad
f_Y(y)
=
\begin{cases}
y & y\in[0,1],
\\
2-y & y\in(1,2],
\\
0 & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
The density of $Z$ is given by the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) of $f_Y$ and $f_X$ (alternatively, you can interchange $f_Y$ and $f_X$ in the next formula, but for me it is easier to think this way since $f_Y$ is more "complicated"):
$$
f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y)f_X(z-y)\, \mathrm dy
$$
Now, being very careful for which $y$ and $z$ the densities $f_Y(y)$ and $f_X(z-y)$ take which values (and being non-zero in particular), we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\text{for }z\in[0,1]:
\qquad
&
f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{z} y\cdot 1\mathrm dy
\\
\text{for }z\in(1,2]:
\qquad
&
f_Z(z) = \int_{z-1}^{1} y\cdot 1\mathrm dy + \int_{1}^{z} (2-y)\cdot 1\mathrm dy
\\
\text{for }z\in(2,3]:
\qquad
&
f_Z(z) = \int_{z-1}^{2} (2-y)\cdot 1\mathrm dy
\\
\text{for all other }z:
\qquad
&
f_Z(z) = 0
\end{align*}
I assume you can figure out the integrals by yourself. I hope I didn't make any typos, which is best verified by checking whether $\rho_Z(z)$ integrates to one.

Comment: Thanks! I arrived at the same answer.